# Error: HTTP error: 400, Project 'my_project' is not a Firestore enabled project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While I run the command `firebase deploy` I get this error:

> Error: HTTP Error: 400, Project 'my_project' is not a Firestore enabled project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, saved my day. Yes, the Firestore database is not created( while the realtime database is initialized), so manually create the Firestore database using default settings, then "firebase deploy" again, OK now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It was just an ignorance while using the firebase console. I just had to enable the firestore beta from the console itself, under Database.

Answer (score 36):

Are you trying to use Cloud Firestore?

- If so, visit the database section of the console and initialize Cloud Firestore
- If not, remove the `firestore.rules` file locally

Answer (score 18):

If you’re not using Cloud Firestore, comment firestore in firebase.json

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. The solution is this: Go to Firebase console and login there [Firebase console]. Here you will see your Recent projects. Go to your project e.g. “stepintothepresent” and then go to database at left side panel, then choose cloud firestore and then I selected the 2nd option.

[image: Firebase Console > Your Firebase Project > Database]

After that I run firebase deploy from command prompt and the result is this

[image: Result from windows command prompt]

Comment: this is good, thanks. It's literally just changing that from realtime Database to Cloud Firestore. But init some stuff and allow it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the REST APIs using below URL:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=

Answer (score 0):

selected Cloud Firestore while initial firebase setup?

Just go to console and enable Cloud Firestore. 
When prompted for once you can select test mode to start off and later change it to private.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a DB environment and it worked fine after that. I'm using the realtime DB, not Cloud storage so it shouldn't have stopped it, anyway, its fixed.

Answer (score -2):

someone with another answer please.

Are you trying to use Cloud Firestore?

If so, visit the database section of the console and initialize Cloud Firestore
* Can you post the url please?

If not, remove the firestore.rules file locally
*Error: Error reading rules file firestore.rules