# error TS6133: 'functions' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tslint, tsconfig

This question may seem like a duplicate to [error TS6133](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815268/src-index-ts11-error-ts6133-functions-is-declared-but-its-value-is-never) but in my case it seems like a  false positive error since I've used the variable in a method but it still complains.

[image]

In my Code I've used the variable as follows

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {DocumentReference, FieldValue, Timestamp}
  from "@google-cloud/firestore";

const app = admin.initializeApp();


exports.onMessageCreate = functions.firestore
    .document( // method body goes here
```

I have modified the tsconfig.json as follows but still the compiler fails on deployment

[image]

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557580/16442705

Comment: I've already made that change. Check the image attached in the last section of the question.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Typescript compiler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700939/how-to-reset-intellisense-in-vs-code#:~:text=Restart%20the%20TypeScript%20language%20service,restart%22%20and%20it%20should%20autosuggest

Comment: It did not work. I setup the project from CLI and just pasted the code without eslint.